# Average of the counts

Tags: matlab, vector, average

This may sound too trivial but I am having some confusion regarding the following logic. I have a vector of distances `D = [1 1.2 4 5 1.9 0 9 0.8 1.13 3]` of length, `M= 10`. I need to keep a record of the count of the distances from vector D which is less than equal to 2. So, count = (1,2,3...etc) i.e discrete. Then I need to find the average such that `Avg_Count = 1\M sum_i=1 to M count_i`

Is the following code correct?

```
D = [1 1.2 4 5 1.9 0 9 0.8 1.13 3];

count = 0;
for I = 1:M
if (D(I)<=2) 
count = count+1;
end

Avg_count = mean(count);
```

The confusion is count contains only one number and the mean of a single number is itself. How do I implement the above logic? Thank you.

Comment: What would `count` be in your example, exactly?

Comment: The distances D are calculated from a reconstructed 2 dimensional time series in phase space from a one dimensional time series by taking sequential pairs of points and instead of the threshold = 2, in my case it is the standard deviation of the time series in 1D. Count in my case are the number of times the distances are less than a threshold. When count=1, Avg_count becomes (M+1)/M. So, Avg_count is the average value of the count's in the sample count = (count1,count2,count3,..,countM) with sample size M. I do not understand what count will be.

Comment: Are you calculating the ratio of less-than-or-eq-two elements in the array `nnz(D <= 2) / numel(D)` or something else? The definition of `count` here sounds very confusing...

Comment: In your code, `count` is just a number, so taking an average is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D = [1 1.2 4 5 1.9 0 9 0.8 1.13 3];

count = zeros(size(D));

running_total = 0;

for i = 1:size(D,2)
    if D(i) < 2
        running_total = running_total + 1;
        count(i) = running_total;
    end
end

Avg_count = mean(count);

count =

   1   2   0   0   3   4   0   5   6   0

Avg_count =  2.1000
```

Comment: @Steve Osborne: This is not what I wanted, unfortunately. You see count should be = (1,2,0,0,3,4,0,5,6,0). Then, doing the average of this vector.

Comment: @SKM Edited the response, now that you helpfully provided some desired output.  :)  Maybe there is a more compact way to accomplish this, but hopefully the above is straightforward to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have at last provided an example of the desired output, I think I understand what you want (at least for the count part; I'm not sure about the average):

```
count = zeros(size(D));
ind = D<=2; %// logical index
count(ind) = 1:nnz(ind); %// fill values indexed by ind
Avg_count = mean(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
D = [1 1.2 4 5 1.9 0 9 0.8 1.13 3]
out = cumsum(D<2) .* (D<2)
mean_value = mean(out)
```

Output -

```
out =
     1     2     0     0     3     4     0     5     6     0

mean_value =
    2.1000
```